# Django Sitemaps Not Showing My Blogposts

Tags: python, django, django-sitemaps

I'm using the Django Sitemap Framework.

You can see my sitemap here:

https://dealmazing.com/sitemap.xml

It seems to be picking up my blog at `/blog`

but not my actual blog posts.  it looks like it is recording the actual posts over and over again as `dealmazing.com/blog` but without the real URL

This is my sitemaps.xml file

```
from django.contrib import sitemaps
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.urls import reverse
from deals.models import Deal, Category, Retailer
from blog.models import Post, BlogCategory

class StaticViewSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    priority = 1.0
    changefreq = 'daily'

    def items(self):
        return ['about', 'contact', 'disclosure', 'terms', 'privacy', 'deals:deals', 'blog:blog']

    def location(self,item):
        return reverse(item)


class BlogSitemap(Sitemap):
    changfreq = "daily"
    priority = 1.0
    location ='/blog'

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(status='Published')

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.created

class BlogCategorySitemap(Sitemap):
    changfreq = "daily"
    priority = 1.0

    def items(self):
        return BlogCategory.objects.all()

class DealCategorySitemap(Sitemap):
    changfreq = "daily"
    priority = 1.0

    def items(self):
        return Category.objects.all()

class RetailerSitemap(Sitemap):
    changfreq = "daily"
    priority = 1.0

    def items(self):
        return Retailer.objects.all()


class DealSitemap(Sitemap):
    changfreq = "daily"
    priority = 1.0

    def items(self):
        return Deal.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.date_added
```

and in my urls file

```
sitemaps = {
    'static': StaticViewSitemap,
    'blog': BlogSitemap,
    'blog-category': BlogCategorySitemap,
    'deals': DealSitemap,
    'deals-category': DealCategorySitemap,
    'retailers': RetailerSitemap
}

 path('sitemap.xml', sitemap,
         {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
         name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
```

I can't quite determine why it is not posting the full URL

Comment: Because of `location ='/blog'`. Consider changing it to a method as you did with `StaticViewSitemap`.

Comment: ok yep--you're right, just removed that and set the get_absolute_url on the model, and works perfect...thanks!